# Why 90% of central region of normal distribution is $\mu\pm qnorm(0.95) \cdot \sigma $

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

**Question:** The average height in a sample is $\mu=170.035$. Using simulation, it can be shown that the probability of the sample average of the height falling within 2 centi-meter of the population average is approximately equal to $\sigma=0.925$.

Using the normal approximation we get that the central region that contains 90% of the distribution of the sample average is of the form $170.035\pm z \cdot 1.122$. The value of $z$ is:

**Its answer: $1.644854$**

**Its explanation:** The structure of the central region that contains 90% of the Normal distribution is:

$\mu \pm qnorm(0.95)\cdot \sigma$

However, $\mu = 170.035$ and $\sigma=1.122$.

Therefore, $z=$ `qnorm(0.95)` $=1.644854$.

---

**My thought:**

Should it be `qnorm(0.90)` $=\mu\pm(z\cdot \sigma)$? Why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The central region that contains 90% of the normal distribution is the one that excludes 5% in the left tail  and 5% in the right one.

Thus the two quantiles are

`qnorm(0.05)`=-1.644854

`qnorm(0.95)`=1.644854

Comment: Arrr, I see. Thank you for your time and answer, @tommik :-)